# Best way to show dynamic lists/columns of items?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have pages per state that lists the cities that our client offers services in. The issue I'm having is that the number of cities differs per page. Some pages have 20 and some might only have 2. Right now, I'm using CSS Grid, which works fine but my team thinks there is a little too much spacing if there are only 2-4 cities but I'm not exactly sure how to target that.

**When there are just 3 cities:**
[image]

**When there are a lot of cities:**
[image]

**CSS**

```
.local-listings {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(175px, 1fr));
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="">
  <ul class="local-listings inline-block text-center w-full mb-6">
  {% for child in page.children.all %}
    <li class="mb-6 md:mb-4"><a href="{{ child.url }}" class="text-cta">{{ child.name }}</a</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This accomplishes more of what I'm trying to do.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min-content, 200px));
```